# Batch file: command line argument substitution

Tags: batch-file, command-line

(I'm no batch files expert. I have gathered the following after going through several online articles)

What's wrong with the following simple script? All I'm trying to do is to replace one sub-string in the command line argument with another string:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion && echo !%1:ftp=https!
```

Batch file name is `test.bat`. When I run this batch file (e.g. `test ftp://example.com`), it prints `//example.com:ftp=https` instead of `https://example.com`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You cannot do substitution with a command line argument. You can only do it with environmental variables.

Comment: aah thanks... i come from C# background. Thought it was just an expression. :)

Comment: Unless you've simplified your example a little too much, why not just use `@For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ("%~1") Do @If "%%~G" == "ftp" Echo https:%%~H`